# $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus

$f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$:

Prove that there exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that

$\frac{b f(a)-a f(b)}{b-a} = f(c) - c f'(c)$.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: @user46944 yeah its   bf(a)−af(b)

Comment: As it is, the claim is false: $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ is a counterexample: $f(x)-x\cdot f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{2}$ for all $x>0$, but $\frac{b f(a)-af(b)}{b-a}=\frac{1\sqrt 0-0\sqrt 1}{1-0}=0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli isn't $f(x) - xf'(x) = \sqrt{x} / 2$?

Comment: @user251257 True, nice catch. The point stays though.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=x^2$, $a=0$, and $b=1$, then
$$ \frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{b-a}=1\cdot0^2-0\cdot 1^2=0 $$
while for any $c\in (0,1)$ we have
$$ f(c)-cf^{\prime}(c)=c^2-2c^2=-c^2<0 $$
Therefore the claim is false as written.

Comment: But it's $bf(a) - af(b)$, not $bf(b) - af(a)$.

Comment: A typo perhaps?

Comment: Only time (and OP) will tell.

Comment: It is   bf(a)−af(b)

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false: I believe it should be like this:
$\frac{b f(a)-a f(b)}{b-a}=f(a)-af'(c)$ for some $c\in (a,b)$

Let $ g(x)=af(x)-xf(a)$. Then
$$ g(a)=0\ \text{ and }\ g(b)=af(b)-bf(a).$$ By MVT
$$\frac{b f(a)-a f(b)}{b-a}=-\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=-g'(c)=f(a)-af'(c)$$
for some $c\in (a,b)$